# emails not sending in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, jruby

I did the same thing as in this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm. it is showing mail sent in output window of net-beans with the message but it is not actually sending the mail. can anyone tell me what could be the problem? 
i have searched a lot but m not getting any solution.

I am using net-beans with `ruby 1.5.1`, `rails 2.3.8`. I have searched but I only got the solution to update `j-ruby`. If it is so then please tell me how to use updated version of `j-ruby` in net-beans.

the following code is in environment.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => 'gmail',
   :user_name => "id@gmail.com",
   :password => "",
   :authentication => 'plain',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

thanks

Comment: can you post the code

Answer (score 0):

Visit the following link for more detail about [Action Mailer.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
Update your mailer settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'gmail',
  :user_name => "id@gmail.com",
  :password => "******",
  :authentication => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Where `******` is your email password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already did it but m not getting any solution.

Comment: whats your actually problem is?

Comment: the problem is it is displaying in output window that the mail is sent but actually mail is not received by the user.

Comment: it is the id password only

Answer (score 0):

can you please check that whether you have do this or not

```
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: if i add the above mentioned line it is giving error as C:/Users/Wish7/Documents/NetBeansProjects/email/config/environment.rb:44: delivery_methodsmtp is not a class/module (TypeError)
        from E:/nupur/netbeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'

Comment: can you please move your code from enviroment.rb to config/application.rb if you used rails > 3  Please let me know after that

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your network provider if your smtp port is open. or check using telnet commands. If you work under a company network which has restrictions on sending mails, you should explicitly ask for permission and get the port opened.

The mail sent message will be shown in output even if it isnt actually sent. So pls make sure you have the following changes made to know the errors in your config/environments/development.rb or production.rb depending on in which mode you are running your server

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: if i add the above mentioned line it is giving error as C:/Users/Wish7/Documents/NetBeansProjects/email/config/environment.rb:44: delivery_methodsmtp is not a class/module (TypeError) from E:/nupur/netbeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initia‌​lizer.rb:111:in `run'

Comment: You need not add this line i suppose.. its already present in ur environments files. you jus need to change false to true

Comment: i did that but now it is giving error jruby-openssl required but it is not getting installed